# How to compress files on MAC M1 and extract on AMD64 machine

Tags: macos, extract, tar

I am trying to compress files on Mac M1 and use it on my old Mac which is on AMD64 architecture. Now I am facing issue when extracting the files on my old Macbook Pro.

```
tar (child): gzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
bash-4.2#
```

I am thinking it is architecture compatiblility issue. Could someone please tell me how to extract files on my AMD64 laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a architecture problem, but most likely a problem with a missing `gzip` installation.
If you are using `homebrew`, you can install gzip with the following command

```
brew install gzip
```

And then try to untar the file again